# Bash assignment statement expansion in POSIX vs. non-POSIX mode

Tags: bash

The [GNU bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) has the following passage while talking about shell parameters:

> The `command` builtin does not prevent builtins that take assignment statements as arguments from expanding them as assignment statements; when not in POSIX mode, assignment builtins lose their assignment statement expansion properties when preceded by command.

I can't figure out what it's talking about, and I also can not manage to write a command that differs in behavior of assignment expressions between regular mode and posix mode for this reason.

Can anyone find an example of this difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can anyone find an example of this difference?

Yes, here you go:

```
$ touch foo=bar
$
$ command declare foo=*
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="bar"
$
$ set -o posix
$ command declare foo=*
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="*"
```

In POSIX mode, `foo=*` doesn't expand to `foo=bar`; it stays verbatim because [pathname expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) isn't performed on assignment statements.

But in normal mode it does; preceding `declare` with `command` causes `foo=*` to be interpreted as a regular argument rather than an assignment statement; thus it undergoes pathname expansion.

And another one:

```
$ foo='x y=z'
$
$ command declare bar=$foo
$ declare -p bar y
declare -- bar="x"
declare -- y="z"
$
$ unset bar y
$ set -o posix
$ command declare bar=$foo
$ declare -p bar y
declare -- bar="x y=z"
bash: declare: y: not found
```

In this case, the difference is that `$foo` undergoes [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) (as it's unquoted) in normal mode, resulting in two separate arguments, `bar=x` and `y=z`. But in POSIX mode the space is retained, and the result of expansion is not split. Hence `bar='x y=z'`.

Comment: out of curiosity do you know what the motivation for this difference in behavior is? I assume that the GNU bash behavior is better in some way

Comment: @user2304936 I don't know, all I could find about this  is [#0000351](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=351).